# How solve experimentalDecorators warning using typescript and PM2?

Tags: node.js, typescript, pm2, tsconfig, tsc

I'm working on a project that uses node.js with typescript. If I run TSC or a command to build the project, it works because I have the option `"experimentalDecorators": true` in my tsconfig.json.

But when I put it into my dev server using pm2 with the same configuration, doesn't work using the exosystem.config.json and without.

First, I have this tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src"],
}
```

My project structure is:

- index.ts
- tsconfig.json
- src/
- ecosystem.config.js

My ecosystem.config.js is:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: './index.ts',
    autorestart: true,
    exec_mode: "fork",
    watch: true,
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
    },
  }
],
};
```

And if I debug the pm2 logs I have this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVeaN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error with this ecosystem.config.js configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'app',
    script: './node_modules/.bin/ts-node',
    args: '-P ./tsconfig.json ./index.ts',
    watch: true,
    restart_delay: 10000,
    wait_ready: true
  }],

};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).